# Selenium IDE - Find id to click

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-ide

i am trying but but make it work:

I have found the id i want to use, but if i try it, it says element not found

```
<div class="WareItem" data-sort="hardware" data-hardware-id="12345" data-reactid="321">
```

I tried with

```
CLICK
css=div[to='data-hardware-id="12345"']
```

EDIT:

i added a picture, please help me :D[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RQdq.png)

Comment: Maybe you need to click a link, or a button and not a div. Add the html for the element that you need to click.

Comment: i tried with css=button but it hasnt worked either ^^

Comment: Add the html for the section of the button if you need help with the selector.

Comment: i did add the html?!   "div class="WareItem" data-sort="hardware" data-hardware-id="12345" data-reactid="321""

Comment: This is the div, you need to click on an button or a link, the html for the button may help. if you need to select this div the selector would be: div[data-hardware-id="12345"]

Comment: hm i think its not a button it is selector for colors, if i click on then i can change the color, thats why i wanted to  use it to select different colors

Comment: It should work the selector i gave, if not please see here few rules to get css selectors http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: not working with div[data-hardware-id="12345"]

Comment: It would need to be css=div[data-hardware-id="12345"]
not just div[data-hardware-id="12345"]

Comment: hello, i was on vacation :D now i am back... with css=div[data-hardware-id="12345"]   its still not working... selenium ide shows as "green" if i click it, but still it isnt selecting the needed hardware

Comment: Nobody an Idea? or should i create a new Thread cause i was on vacation? MODS? :D